# Blocking Web Requests made by certain webpage (Via Extension)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

So i know how to block requests made to a certain website, but how would you block/track/filter out requests made by a certain website? For example, a webpage named `good.com` makes a request to `evil.com`. The goal is to block that request to `evil.com` if and only if it's made by `good.com`. This is the simple method of blocking a site no matter where the request was made from (From chrome's [Dev Page on Web Requests](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest))

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
    function(details) {
      return {cancel: details.url.indexOf("://www.evil.com/") != -1};
    },
    {urls: ["<all_urls>"]},
    ["blocking"]);
```

Edit- not sure how much it matters, but this is running in the background of a chrome extension (With permission to all webpages)

If I were to change the permissions to (for continuity with the above example) strictly `good.com`, would the extension only be able to block requests from that site? This really wouldn't be ideal because there's some functionality within my extension that requires these permissions.

Comment: Is anything wrong with using `details.tabId` and `details.frameId` to get the url of the site?

Comment: @wOxxOm It will be too late: getting the details of a page is async.

Comment: @Xan, good point but isn't it quite easy to maintain a list using `tabs.onUpdated` or `webNavigation` events like `tabUrl[tabId+"."+frameId] = url`? (of course 'maintaining' implies that old elements should be deleted when a tab is closed or its url changes)

Comment: It is a possible solution, yes. I was just pointing out what's wrong with your first idea.